What is causing volume to change in Windows 10?
I have Windows 10 installed.
I have 2 sound devices connected:

Speakers.
USB headphones+mic set.

lately even though the volume is set to a low setting every once in a while if I start a new activity that has sound it seems to spike up (although the bar is still set to the low volume setting).
Only when I press again on the low setting the volume is lowered again (until the next time it happens).
Any idea what is causing it and how to stop it?

Usually human, pressing something or having a random application that messes with volume. This, without any m ore details, is unanswerable

@Destroy666 only open apps (that im aware of) are firefox and avast. if there is a way to check for volume change events and what caused it, that would also be a good clue

@Destroy666 just mentioning - like i stated in the question - the volume setting stays on 18 but the sound spikes like its 100 and only when i press on the bar again does it drop back, there is no change to the volume bar itself
